# How to avoid worsening lag/slow-down in Unity 2D Runner?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got error in script or it's a bug, I don't know. When I start the game first time it goes very smooth, but after I play sometime like 20 sec, player starts moving slower and slower, and at the end he almost doesn't move.

The game is Endless Runner, when I die I press retry, and then it get slower after every retry.

Script

```
 void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
    {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
            newPosition.y += Mathf.Clamp(touch.deltaPosition.y * speed, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            transform.position = newPosition;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you instantiating objects for your runner? Is this done via object pooling, or are you using `Instantiate()`? Are you destroying these objects afterwards if they're instantiated? Use the Unity profiler to determine what's bogging down your game, then update your question accordingly if you find anything interesting.

Comment: @Serlite I am using object destroyer, when objects goes behind the screen it gots destroyed, and after retry i load the game scene again , and every objects start going from zero , but player movement starts to going slower and slower i want to make my player to my on y axis something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeW6SCQv--o watch 13:00-13:05 , in video object is moving on x axis i want to move them on y axis , i am newbie to programming , so your help would be very good, sorry for bad english

Comment: If it's slowing down as the game progresses, please do look at the [Unity Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to figure out where the performance issue is stemming from. It's a really useful tool that you should get to know.

Comment: You need to narrow down the source of the problem. Just try ` newPosition.y += 1;` to check that the way you move the player is not slowing down. 
Then make sure you are destroying everything you instantiate once it's off the screen. (Check them in the scene hierarchy, make sure they disappear)

Comment: @MariamSeleem Didnt get it newPosition.y += 1;

Comment: @MariamSeleem it tryed Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
            newPosition.y += 1; , but player doesnt move.

Comment: Are you updating the `transform.position` after you increase your y ?

Comment: @MariamSeleem Hello can you check my other post? i`am not using this script anymore http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132443/unity-player-movement-y-axissomething-like-swing-copters

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
newPosition.y += Mathf.Clamp(touch.deltaPosition.y * speed, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

when you multiply **touch.deltaPosition * speed**, you are in a most probable scenario limiting the total speed with each frame, unless you are tapping really unfrequently.

If you are trying to make the character go faster with each touch, I recommend using a rigidbody instead of changing its position.

Finally you can simplify your code a little bit by adding a new Vector3, something like

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0,Mathf.Clamp(touch.deltaPosition.y * speed, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * Time.fixedDeltaTime,0);
    }
```

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132374/unity-2d-runner-input-touches-help-needed

Comment: Hello , i dont want to make it go faster after each touch i want him just to move up and down.something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeW6SCQv--o    ... 13:00 -13:05 , but no x axis but y axis

Comment: It still doesnt work , it slowers and slowers every time ,please help out